# How To Create a DataTable In Xamarin Form Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, datatable

I want to create a DataTable in Xamarin Form.

I've searched listview, gridview, ... but I can't find any results.

I want to design the DataTable like the below image. How can I create it?  Is there a keyword to create it?

[image: DataTable]

Comment: You were on the right track with ListView or GridView. What went wrong?

Comment: I did not find the same results as the picture

Comment: As @Crowcoder stated, ListView would work fine, just define a custom ViewCell that formats a single row of data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution that would look like that. But it is possible to style ListView like that - you would need to set separators to None, use BoxView to draw the lines, use Grid in each line and define its columns in such a way to ensure that they are the same in each row.

So no one line solution, but if you try with the instructions from the above you can make it.

Answer (score 0):

Use following to create DataTable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication91
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
        }
    }

}
```